# ADFS as external identity provider for IdentityServer4 via OIDC

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, angular8, openid-connect, adfs

Have anyone connected to ADFS as external provider for Identity Server 4 using OpenId Connect. I'm trying to do in asp.net core 3 application with Angular as front-end. Is there any guide?

Comment: I'm researching the same thing, I'm looking at the following to try https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2580    I'm waiting for information about our ADFS to start my testing, but if this works for you, let me know :-)